# Androidviewclient not showing the Unique ID's on Android4.4.2 OS

Tags: mobile, automation, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.4-kitkat, androidviewclient

Unique IDs are not getting displayed when devices with Android 4.4.2 Kitkat OS devices.Below is the code I am using from examples.

```
import sys
import os

# PyDev sets PYTHONPATH, use it
try:
for p in os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(':'):
if not p in sys.path:
sys.path.append(p)
except:
pass

try:
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
pass

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(verbose=True)).traverse(transform=ViewClient.TRAVERSE_CIT)
```

Samsung OS4.4.2 - Same behavior is observed on Nexus5 with OS 4.4.2

```
android.widget.FrameLayout  
android.widget.LinearLayout  
android.widget.FrameLayout android:id/content 
android.widget.FrameLayout com.sec.android.app.launcher:id/animation_layer 
android.widget.FrameLayout com.sec.android.app.launcher:id/home_view 
android.widget.FrameLayout com.sec.android.app.launcher:id/home_container 
android.widget.FrameLayout  
android.view.View com.sec.android.app.launcher:id/workspace 
android.view.View  
android.view.View  
android.view.View  
android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView  
android.widget.FrameLayout  
android.widget.LinearLayout com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:id/search_plate 
android.widget.LinearLayout
```

LG G2 OS 4.2

```
android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/1 
android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/2 
android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/3 
android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/4 
android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/5 
android.view.View id/no_id/6 
android.view.View id/no_id/7 
android.view.View id/no_id/8 
android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView id/no_id/9 
android.widget.FrameLayout id/no_id/10 
android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/11 
android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/12 
android.widget.ImageButton id/no_id/13 
android.widget.LinearLayout id/no_id/14 
android.widget.ImageButton id/no_id/15 
android.widget.TextView id/no_id/16 Log Viewer
android.widget.TextView id/no_id/17 CatLog
```

Also, vc.findViewById('id/tv_search').type('Donald') is not working. But ID-'id/no_id/23' is working fine on all the devices.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I can't see any View with `id/tv_search` in your sample. A good starting point to fix any of these findX() method problems is to use `culebra` to generate a template script.

Comment: **AndroidViewClient** can provide only the ids given by `uiautomator dump`, if ids are not there on some device, you can trust the **unique ids** which are assigned in order of appearance and should be the same for the same app.

Comment: My question is why I am getting two different type of ID's with the same script. On kitkat devices, I am getting ID's which are given by our developers while developing the app. On 4.2.2 devices, I am getting AVC default ID's.

Above is the example I mentioned. i.e id/tv_search is the id of an element on OS 4.4.2 and id/no_id/23 is the id of the same element on OS 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting different results because even though the script is the same the back end (`uiautomator` in this case) returns different data for the same application. Previously, `uiautomator` was not returning the ids on any version but it was improved in KitKat to do it. This issue was one of the reasons why if you needed ids you had to resort to other back end alternatives like ViewServer or LocalViewServer.

**AndroidViewClient** tries to deal with all these differences in android versions and implementations a provide you with a single interface (and this is where unique ids are assigned) to allow you to create cross-version test scripts.

Comment: Thanks Milano for quick replies. Is it possible to touch the Device id i.e id/tv_search instead of AVC default ID. AVC is not able to recognise the id's other than default IDs. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Reason for working with App ID's instead of Unique IDs is, My application is having multiple screens and in each screen it is having same id's eg: id/no_id/10. Also, I have a relative layout in our app, due to this, Base on the background screen, Unique AVC ID's are changing. Sometimes, it is id/no_id/10, some times, it is id/no_id/12 etc., 

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Definitely, APP IDs are preferred if available, you're totally right, but this only happens in kitKat as i mentioned. Yes, you can touch or whatever once you have a reference to the View.

Comment: Yeah, but whats happening in Kitkat is, when I use app ID's it is not recognising and doing any action, but it is working when I use Default ID's. How to overcome this?

Comment: They should be recognized, you may be doing something wrong.

Comment: I am getting all the list of Id's when I use the below code. But I am not able to do any action.
ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()).traverse(transform=ViewClient.TRAVERSE_CIT)

Comment: I recommended you to use `culebra` so you can start your script from something that has already the `findViewX()` methods with the right arguments.

Comment: Thanks Milano. I will recheck my code and will let you know.